# Navigation bar title color change for iPad

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

For navigation Title i have set text About which is display in white background color!

when i run on ipad it in gray background

```
"#Win_aboutUs":{
     backgroundColor:'white',
    backgroundImage:'images/windowBackground.png',
    title:"About Us",
    layout:'vertical',
    font:{fontSize:'16',fontFamily:'Arial',fontWeight:'bold'},
    barImage:'images/u9_normal.png',
    navBarHidden:false
}
```

how to change the the text color to white

Comment: Just set a color attribute and set it to white : {color:'white'}

Comment: Us I did that color: 'white'! Still same issue

Comment: Try this : barColor: '#999'

Comment: @anilMotwani yes its worked